# How could someone dismantle Mother's Day in the United States?

Tags: society, culture, time-keeping

[Anna Jarvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Jarvis) was the founder of Mother's Day in the United States. Ironically, she spent the rest of her life trying to dismantle it because she felt it was too commercialized. Her efforts failed, so it's still celebrated today.

Let's say that someone in the modern day wanted to succeed where Jarvis failed and dismantle Mother's Day in the United States. In other words, my goals are:

- Stop Mother's Day from being a federally recognized holiday
- Severely diminish the number of greeting cards, flowers, and other things sold for the occasion
- Reduce the awareness of Mother's Day in the popular consciousness (when was the last time somebody celebrated Temperance Sunday?)

How could they go about doing this with the least amount of risk and money spent?

Comment: I like the question, but I'm voting to close as too broad because you need to pick a specific holiday and a specific country.  The methods to take down Christmas (see Pratchett's *Hogfather*) will be very, very different compared to taking down Valentine's Day, St. Patrick's Day, or Mother's Day - and that's only when considering a U.S. perspective.  Be warned, even after making this not "too broad" you may still have a POB hurdle to get over.  You'll need to tell us how to judge the best answer. (\*continued\*)

Comment: It's worth noting that this site is commonly used to ask, "I'm just curious" questions, even though they are NOT a good fit for the site.  According to the [help/on-topic], questions must be specific and answerable, must include context, must include restrictions/requirements, and should include research.  "I'm just curious" questions are notorious for being/having none of that.  So, it's not enough to be specific, you need to avoid POB, too.

Comment: This seems to boil down to "How do I influence a lot of people without many resources?" Rejecting the obvious conclusion ("you probably cannot"), we are left with  "you must be charismatic, creative, organized, disciplined,...and very lucky." That answer is simply too broad and shallow for this venue. If it were easy, everybody would do it.

Comment: Did you forget to buy your mother something?

Comment: @JBH I've narrowed it down to Mother's Day in the US specifically and taken out the restriction of an average salary. Does that address your concerns, or is there more I can do? I'm not sure what "POB" stands for, by the way.

Comment: POB = [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  Basically, you need to ask a question that clearly you can judge a best answer for.  That's why the [help/on-topic] requires context and restrictions/requirements.  If we don't see where you're going, then you might as well roll dice to pick the best answer, and that's off-topic.  What's your goal?  What does "dismantle" mean?  Etc.

Comment: Just reviewed your edit. It could be opened as no longer too broad perhaps, it would still generate POB answers and should therefore be closed again that way. Shame, the answers would probably be of interest in spite of this, I decided therefore to vote to reopen. (I declare personal bias, I'm not jockeying for position as a mod after all and have freedom to hold an opinion).

Answer (score 2):

In today's social political climate, with all the testosterone apologism that is going on,
all that a person needs to do to destroy Mother's day is to announce on social media that Motherhood deserves more than one day per year.  That in fact, without Mothers, none of us would be here at all.  So everyday should be Mother's day.

Dilute something special down to every day mediocrity, and it will be destroyed more thoroughly than if you forbade it, outlawed it and made celebrating it, punishable by death.  Consider the 92 million people worth of restaurant staff who are currently ignoring the idea that Sunday is a day of rest.  Familiarity breeds dilution and dilution leads...

nowhere.

Comment: Could be onto something except I'd say make it politically correct to the point that nobody want to celebrate it thus "Non Gender Specific Parental Guardian Day" was born.......

Answer (score 0):

Likely closing bars and restaurants would take the air out of the holiday pretty quickly.  Apparently, [92 million](https://www.qsrmagazine.com/news/92-million-americans-will-eat-out-mother-s-day) people eat out on Mother's Day.

Comment: This answer might be improved by also mentioning how many people eat out on a normal day (or a normal Sunday, really), to give that figure some context.

Answer (score 0):

**Terrorism**

Basically you have very little money and no real influence so nobody cares what you think. People are making money from it so it won't stop.

The only solution is to strike fear into people so they are too scared to celebrate it.

Sprinkle anthrax on some Mother's Day flowers, spike some chocolates or even snipe people carrying balloons.

Get known by the media as the "Mother's Day Killer". Don't be an idiot and brag to the police. Use different methods and hit different areas. Avoid a pattern other than hitting on Mother's Day.

Finally watch society become scared of Mother's Day when copy cats repeat your crimes.

Comment: Just how much terror can one person cause? Remember, school shootings haven't stopped people going to school; serial killers haven't stopped people going out alone; the IRA did manage to get of public bins, but that's about it. Plus the risk of being "...a lone wolf with mother issues..." (i.e., getting caught)

Comment: School shootings the person doesn't get away. Remember the trouble that sniper caused from that white car. He only got caught cause he bragged to the police. He'd still be going if he had kept his mouth shut.